# Unable to install Jenkins via Linux package manager

Tags: jenkins, centos

I am unable to install jenkins, it shows no package jenkins available.

This is what I have tried.

1. enable the port 8080
2. installed java
3. copied the commands from jenkins
4. "yum install -y jenkins"

```
[root@learninginsatance kumarpgdmk]# yum install -y jenkins
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.centos.iad1.serverforge.org
 * epel: ord.mirror.rackspace.com
 * extras: mirrors.gigenet.com
 * updates: centos.mirrors.hoobly.com
No package jenkins available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 0):

before you can use **yum install jenkins**, you have to add the repository in your list of repositories.

```
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo \
    https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo
sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key
sudo yum upgrade
sudo yum install jenkins java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```

follow this

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#red-hat-centos